# Reference List Box Column by Field Name

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have an MS Access form in which selection of a list box item determines how many other aspects of the application behave.

I have a table containing an ID and description and several other fields which correspond to settings for other aspects of the application; this table is the `Row Source` of the list box.

The list box is configured such that the first two columns (ID & Description) are visible, with the widths of the remaining columns set to `0` - the `Column Widths` property of the list box is therefore something like:

```
1cm;5cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm
```

Within my application I then reference the remaining fields using expressions such as:

```
MyListBox.Column(n)
```

However, this relies heavily on the order of the fields in the table, and if I then decide to add another field to my table, I have to:

- Increment the list box Column Count
- Add another zero to the semi-colon delimited Column Widths
- Potentially change the identifiers used in the various `Column(n)` statements, depending on where the new field was added in the table.

My original reason for using this approach was to avoid the need to repeatedly open a RecordSet to obtain the values of the additional fields associated with the item selected from the list box.

**Is there a way to reference list box fields by field name rather than by column number?**

(Or is there an entirely better way to approach this task?)

Comment: Use a dictionary or a collection then youcould reference them by key without opening/closing recordsets

Comment: You could also use dlookup on the table as well

Comment: you could also dynamically change the listbox on the form open event so that way you never have to touch it again. The more I think about it there are just a bazillion ways to handle this efficiently

Comment: A direct answer to the question is no. You will have to find other methods to accomplish, as suggested by @DougCoats. Why do you need all these fields available? Why would you have to add a field?

Comment: @DougCoats Thank you for your suggestions - I hadn't considered using a Dictionary or Collection, either of which could be updated on the `AfterUpdate` event of the List Box. Many thanks.

Comment: @June7 As noted in my question, the fields contain flags/parameters which control the behaviour & output of other elements of the application - additional fields may be added as requirements change or the application is enhanced - though, I don't see that this is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm hearing a lot of *No, not possible*, this actually is possible for list boxes that have a row source type of *Table/Query*, by using the `ListBox.RecordSet` property.

For combo boxes, this is easy, since the recordset moves along with the selected value. For list boxes, it doesn't, so you will have to know the name and position of the ID column (or, if the ID column is the bound column, just use the `.Value` property)

Example:

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.List1.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "ID = " & Me.List1.Value
Debug.Print rs.Fields!Field1
```

Add code to check if a value is selected, if the recordset property is set, and if a match is found if needed.

Comment: So still need to open recordset object? OP said reason for including all those fields in listbox RowSource was to avoid that.

Comment: You're cloning the already open list recordset, not opening a new one. There's a difference. If you don't want an open recordset object, you can't use a list box with a table as a row source.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thank you for offering this alternative. My original relunctance to using recordsets was to avoid having to open a new recordset with a query set to match on the bound column of the list box for every function in which the list box fields are referenced. I suppose this approach is similar, but maybe more efficient. My question ultimately stems from not knowing the industry best-practice and hence doubting whether I'm missing something obvious in my approach.

Comment: Well, as said, there's a pretty significant difference between cloning and opening a new recordset. When cloning, you don't need to fetch records that have already been fetched, you don't need to set new locks, and you probably lose _very_ little performance compared to specifying the column number. The seek is going to cost you some, but not that much. Afaik Access VBA lacks _industry best-practice_ altogether, being a pretty niche language.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Many thanks for the explanation. Any idea why my original question would be downvoted? Did it not fulfil some house rules?

Comment: I imagine it's related to people thinking it's not possible. People don't like being asked the impossible. However, explaining downvotes is beyond my skill. It might be [Tim losing his keys yet again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/369403).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Brilliant story! :-)

Comment: It *is* possible.  I think this answer is addressing an issue that is different than the question that was in bold in the original post.  I gave the question an upvote because it didn't deserve a -1.

Answer (score 2):

#### Get the value from a list box/combo box by referencing its field name

I have a listbox that contains 30+ columns but only a few are visible.  When a row in the listbox is selected, I need to grab values from columns on the selected row and display them in other fields or use them to enable/disable other controls.  Over the years there have been various people supporting this application and sometimes a column gets added or re-positioned in a new order.  This causes havoc for references like this:

```vb
        txtFlow_Peak = lstPOC_ID.Column(27)
        txtFlow_Avg = lstPOC_ID.Column(29)
```

It's hard to debug code written like this and keep track of each column position.

I had an idea to reference each column by name instead of by its column position and I created a function to make the code more readable and writable.

```vb
        txtFlow_Peak = GetColumnValueFromName(lstPOC_ID, "Flow_Peak")
        txtFlow_Avg = GetColumnValueFromName(lstPOC_ID, "Flow_Avg")
```

> Is there a way to reference list box fields by field name rather than
>   by column number?

I believe this function or the method used within it addresses your question.  The error handler will show you the available field names if you try to address a column name that is not present.

```vb
Public Function GetColumnValueFromName(ctl As Control, ColumnName As String) As String
' Pass in a listbox/combobox control and a column name and return the value from that column.
' This lets you address a column by its name instead of the index which can be awkward
' if there are a lot of columns.
' This code is expecting a control that is bound to a Table/Query.
' Ben S. - 11/8/2019

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim fld As Field

    If ctl.Recordset Is Nothing Then
        ' Recordset is not loaded.
    ElseIf ctl.ListIndex = -1 Then
        ' No current row.
    Else
        'Debug.Print ctl.Name; Tab(20); "Column " & ColumnName & " (" & ctl.Recordset.Fields(ColumnName).OrdinalPosition & ") = '" & ctl.Column(ctl.Recordset.Fields(ColumnName).OrdinalPosition) & "'"

        GetColumnValueFromName = ctl.Column(ctl.Recordset.Fields(ColumnName).OrdinalPosition)  
    End If

Exit_Function:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

    Debug.Print "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - "
    strMsg = "Error #" & err.Number & " - " & err.Description & vbCrLf & "in procedure GetColumnValueFromName" & vbCrLf
    strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & "Control name = " & ctl.Name _
        & vbCrLf & "Passed column name = '" & ColumnName & "'" & vbCrLf

    If err.Number = 3265 Then ' Item not found in this collection.
        ' Build a list of columns in the recordset to help the developer pick the correct column name.
        strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & "Available Columns:" & vbCrLf
        For Each fld In ctl.Recordset.Fields
            strMsg = strMsg & fld.OrdinalPosition & " - " & fld.Name & vbCrLf
        Next
    End If

    Debug.Print strMsg
    MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, "GetColumnValueFromName()"

    GoTo Exit_Function
    Resume Next
    Resume
End Function
```

As a bonus, I have a simpler function that can return the name of a column if you pass in the index.

```vb
Public Function GetColumnNameFromIndex(ctl As Control, ColumnIndex As Long) As String
' Pass in a listbox/combobox control and a column number and return
' the field name of that column.
' Ben S. - 11/8/2019

    If ctl.Recordset Is Nothing Then
        ' Recordset is not loaded.
    ElseIf ctl.ListIndex = -1 Then
        ' No current row.
    Else
        'Debug.Print ctl.Name; Tab(20); "Column " & ctl.Recordset.Fields(ColumnIndex).Name & " (" & ColumnIndex & ") = '" & ctl.Column(ColumnIndex) & "'"

        GetColumnNameFromIndex = ctl.Recordset.Fields(ColumnIndex).Name
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I shared a function to answer a similar question for ADO recordsets. **Returning the index of a field in a recordset** https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773783/1898524

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the column names and stop when you find the one one you want and return the position number.

The below function should do it for you.

```
Public Function fn_find_lb_column(lb As ListBox, strColName As String)

   'this function returns the position of a column in a list box

    Dim intColPos As Integer
    Dim intColCount As Integer

    intColCount = lb.ColumnCount

    'Debug.Print lb.RowSource

    intColPos = -1

    For i = 0 To intColCount - 1
    
       'Debug.Print lb.Column(i, 0)
        If strColName = lb.Column(i, 0) Then
            intColPos = i
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i

exit_here:

    fn_find_lb_column = intColPos

    Exit Function

err_h:

    intColPos = -1

    Resume exit_here

End Function
```

Here's how you would call it.

```
ColumnPos = fn_find_lb_column(Me!ListBox, "ColumnName"))
ColumnVal = Me!ListBox.Column(ColumnPos)
```

OR

```
ColumnVal = Me!ListBox.Column(fn_find_lb_column(Me!ListBox, "ColumnName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

lblComments.Caption = Nz(ListBox.Recordset!Comments, "")

I hope it's self explanatory.